# Importing data from multiple .csv files into single DataFrame

Tags: arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe, glob

I'm having trouble getting data from several .csv files into a single array. I can get all of the data from the .csv files fine, I just can't get everything into a simple numpy array. The name of each .csv file is important to me so in the end I'd like to have a Pandas DataFrame with the columns labeled by the initial name of the .csv file.

```
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("*.csv")

temp_dict = {}
wind_dict = {}

for file in files:
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    temp_dict[file[:-4]] = data['HLY-TEMP-NORMAL'].values
    wind_dict[file[:-4]] = data['HLY-WIND-AVGSPD'].values

temp = []
wind = []
name = []

for word in temp_dict:
    name.append(word)
    temp.append(temp_dict[word])
for word in wind_dict:
    wind.append(wind_dict[word])

temp = np.array(temp)    
wind = np.array(wind)
```

When I print temp or wind I get something like this:

```
[array([ 32.1,  31.1,  30.3, ...,  34.9,  33.9,  32.9])
 array([ 17.3,  17.2,  17.2, ...,  17.5,  17.5,  17.2])
 array([ 41.8,  41.1,  40.6, ...,  44.3,  43.4,  42.6])
 ...
 array([ 32.5,  32.2,  31.9, ...,  34.8,  34.1,  33.7])]
```

when what I really want is:

```
[[ 32.1,  31.1,  30.3, ...,  34.9,  33.9,  32.9]
 [ 17.3,  17.2,  17.2, ...,  17.5,  17.5,  17.2]
 [ 41.8,  41.1,  40.6, ...,  44.3,  43.4,  42.6]
 ...
 [ 32.5,  32.2,  31.9, ...,  34.8,  34.1,  33.7]]
```

This does not work but is the goal of my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(temp, columns=name)
```

And when I try to use a DataFrame from Pandas each row is its own array which isn't helpful because it thinks every row has only element in it. I know the problem is with "array(...)" I just don't know how to get rid of it. Thank you in advance for your time and consideration.

Comment: What is `temp` before converting to `array` ?

Comment: Can you add some sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
files = glob.glob("*.csv")
#read each file to list of DataFrames
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp) for fp in files]
#create names for each file
lst4 = [x[:-4] for x in files]
#create one big df with MultiIndex by files names
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=lst4)
```

---

If want separately `DataFrame`s change last row above solution with reshape:

```
df = pd.concat(dfs, keys=lst4).unstack()

df_temp = df['HLY-TEMP-NORMAL']
df_wind = df['HLY-WIND-AVGSPD']
```